# How exactly the network bandwidth is calculated and in which layer of OSI Model?

Tags: networking, cloud, bandwidth, isp

We can see everyday our bandwidth is calculated by ISP's , Mobile Telecoms and Cloud Services.
But how exactly they calculate this bandwidth?
**Do they count number of tcp/udp packets in layer 4?**
If so, do they ignore icmp packets?

Comment: I think you are confusing bandwidth and throughput. The bandwidth is a function of the physical network. For example, 100Base-TX ethernet has a bandwidth of 100 Mbps, but there are factors that reduce the throughput to something less than that, even though the bandwidth is always 100 Mbps.

Answer (score 2):

Networking concepts don't really map well to OSI layers: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite#Layer_names_and_number_of_layers_in_the_literature

But typically a provider will count traffic at the lowest level it can measure and distinguish individual customers and use that as the input for their bandwidth calculations, fair use policy and/or billing.

Typically that will be either the [internet layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_layer) or the [link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_layer)

How that maps to the OSI model depends on where that provider operates, probably  somewhere between layer 1 and layer 4 :

- a cloud operator will probably monitor traffic in the network virtualization software component on the hypervisor where a virtual server instance runs and not on the switch port that the hypervisor is wired into. Such a virtual network that exists only in software would technically be the [transport layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) I think.
- your ISP might count the bytes in frames on your ADSL subscriber line
- etc.